# JavaScript: how this number came as output

Tags: javascript, function

This code works fine, but, this results `"1number"`. My doubt is how this `'number'`is coming? Any help?

```
var x = 1;
  if (function f(){}) { 
    x += typeof f;
  }
  x;
  alert(x);
```

Comment: You add 1 and "number". That's all.

Comment: Why would you even write that?

Comment: I think it should be `1undefined`.

Comment: It doesn't say `1number` for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vLce00c9/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol This is one of the questions from some Javascript quiz, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Your `number` comes from `typeof f`

Comment: @DerVampyr because you don't have the whole code

Comment: you will get 1number if you have a number variable named 'f'

Comment: How can this be upvoted ???

Comment: Interesting though -- I couldn't tell you offhand why the function declaration doesn't hoist `f` and have it output `1function` offhand. I mean, it doesn't, but why doesn't it?

Comment: @dystroy may be becoz weird. lol

Comment: The possible answer to this question is that you get this result (`1undefined` or `1number`) because `function f(){}` is a truthy value, so you enter `if` block.

Comment: I guess the real quiz question was with only one variable (replace f with x)

Comment: This question should probably be deleted. It seems to just be taken from some homework with absolutely 0 understanding on the part of the asker.

Comment: @ruffin: only function declarations are hoisted. Here we have a function expression and the name of the function expression does not create a local binding.

Comment: If you don't know how typeof works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof .

Comment: Here we go. Here is the quiz (original?) which mentions this question, there are also explanations (Question 9). http://kourge.net/node/130

Comment: @FelixKling That's interesting. The "embedded" alert in this: `if (f = function (){}, alert("1: " + typeof f))` gives `1: function`, but `if (function f(){}, alert("3: " + typeof f))` gives `3: undefined`. I would have thought a named function (`f = function () {}`) == (if not ===) a function declaration with a name (`function f() {}`), as that's how the two seem to behave in a "conventional" code block ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zs9pswuv/)). Not sure I grok exactly why not yet, but that's interesting.

Comment: @ruffin: The name of a function expression is only accessible inside the function itself. `f = function () {}` is not a named function expression, it's an anonymous function assigned to variable `f`. Maybe this helps: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: @FelixKling "*The reason it is an expression is again due to a context: "(" and ")" constitute a grouping operator and grouping operator can only contain an expression:*" I missed the [obvious] connection with `(function foo(){})` Great link. Plus stupid error in logic on my part: The `f =` in my fiddle was really `window.f =`, which was a sort of short-circuiting, like when you're exporting an object out of an expression. `if (var f = function (){}, alert("4: " + typeof f)) {}`, which is really what I should have been testing, would give `Unexpected token var`. I'm back on board; thanks. ;^)

Answer (score 1):

More specifically you're concatenating 1 with the string "number".

`typeof` will return a string, and when you call `+` with `1`, it assumes you want to treat `1` as a string and fuses them together.

Comment: But as @David says, it's giving `1undefined`.

Comment: He will get 1number if he has a number variable named 'f' that we dont see here.

Comment: Yeah, all I could figure is that the code is out of context. But why doesn't the `f` hoist? Does `if` have its own scope? That's interesting.

Comment: @ruffin It is a function expression, not a function declaration.